# Educators' slang: "taking people from where they are"

Tags: expressions

Imagine somebody organising an educational event (e.g. a conference) and trying to set up the programme in a way that everybody attending is being "taken from where they are", meaning: the programme has offers both for beginners, advanced and experts, and nobody would feel left out or not considered, and everybody has a chance to join and contribute.

In German there is a common expression for this:

> Alle wurden abgeholt

which translates to "everybody was picked up", but I am not sure if this English sentence can be used in this metaphorical way, and I suppose there are other expressions used in English for a situation like this.

What good ways are there in English to express this concept?

Comment: Something similar to '*for all levels*' I think, not sure how to phrase it exactly though - what is the sentence you want to put this sentiment into?

Comment: @Smock  The context is: we have feedback statements by participants of that conference, and one said (in German) something like: *The conference was well organised in so far as everybody was picked up at their level.* (I translated this off the cuff now; no idea if this is an acceptable sentence.) As I said, *Alle wurde abgeholt* can be called educators' slang in German.

Comment: '*picked up at their level*' reads fine and is perfectly understandable - I wouldn't change it.

Comment: @Smock  - Thank you. You are, of course, welcome to write an official answer based on this, if you like (regardless of me mentioning it first in the above comment; it was anyway only due to your commenting input).

Comment: @Smock - It is not understandable to me.  *Picked  up* either means *lifted* or *added to [a team]*.  I do not get the impression that ALL of these people will be *added to [a team]*, only that such an opportunity will exist.  If you are merely *offering* the opportunity to participate to ALL, then *picked up* does not describe that situation.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann - Are you trying to say something like, *Regardless of your experience [skill level, educational background], we have a program for you*?   P.S. *Educator's Slang* is also a phrase that I do not understand.

Comment: I'm leaving this open because I can't think of a comparable English expressions, so searching for it would likely turn up nothing

Comment: @EllieK  Yes, *die Teilnehmer abholen* (pick up the participants) could be used in the situation you describe by *regardless of your experience we have a program for you*). But this would refer to an event where various different activities (easy ones, difficult ones) are offered. However, the *abholen* term can also refer to situations where everybody does the same thing, but this thing is set up in a way fitting their needs exactly (i.e. a homogenous audience).

Comment: @EllieK *picked up* is not being used in the literal sense here. It's more like continuing or starting something. Consider the phrase *I picked up some Spanish on holiday*

Answer (score 2):

Just to form this as an answer from comments:

> *picked up at their level*
>
> Example usage:
>   The conference was well organised in so far as everybody was *picked up at their level*.

This was reached by Christian Geiselmann after input from myself.

Comment: Does *picked up at their level* mean someone lifted them up until they could look at each other eye to eye?

Comment: @EllieK That would be, "... picked up **to** their level." Here, "at" means where the person was picked up from, which is at their own level.

Comment: If you imagine a metaphorical "conference bus", picking people up (letting them get on/join) at their level of expertise. So I would imagine, in this instance, the conference might have started out easy to include those with low knowledge, but then progressed to the point where even the very knowledgeable felt it was at their level.